# Second Screen not working Ubuntu 14.04 Intel Graphics

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, screen, intel

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while now so I'll appreciate your help.

I can't make ubuntu 14.04 recognise my second monitor.

This is my graphics card info

```
    ~# lspci | grep -i vga

    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

I've installed the Intel graphics drivers from 
[this page](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/) but  it's still not working.

I also tried this comand to update the drivers but they are up to date of course

```
    ~# sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel

    Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
    Creando árbol de dependencias       
    Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
    xserver-xorg-video-intel ya está en su versión más reciente.
    0 actualizados, 0 se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
```

I've run this

```
    ~# xrandr | grep connected
```

and this is the result (i thought it would be usefull)

```
    xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
    default connected primary 1366x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
```

Thanks for reading this, everything you can say about it will be helpful